# No pairs in a list.

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

This is a difficult problem that I've been thinking for some time with little success and was wondering if anyone will have a look at it for me? First of all I want to clarify something before we start, in an unsorted list a pair exists if two adjacent elements in the list have the same value. It seems obvious but it's good to know for later.

Let $A$ be an unsorted list of size $2n$ which contains the numbers $1,...,n$ exactly twice. How many of these lists will have no pairs?

To give an example for $n=2$, $[1,2,1,2]$ is a list with no pairs. Another example but for $n=3$ is $[1,3,2,3,1,2]$.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "unordered list"? Quite obviously, it has some sort of order on it if you can describe elements as being "adjacent". perhaps you mean "unsorted"?

Comment: @PaulSinclair I assume that the list is an ordered arrangement of numbers, but the numbers themself don't need to be in the right order. The only ordered list in this case would be $1, 1, 2, 2, \ldots, n, n$.

Comment: @Dominik Such a list is more normally referred to (at least in my experience) as "unsorted", meaning that the elements have an order, but are not listed in that order. Since he used "unordered" instead, i am asking for a clarification to make sure I understand his intent.

Comment: yes i do mean unsorted.

Answer (score 1):

[A114938](http://oeis.org/A114938) --   Number of permutations of the multiset {1,1,2,2,....,n,n} with no two consecutive terms equal.

2, 30, 864, 39480, 2631600, 241133760, ...

Answer (score 1):

Let $S$ be the set of arrangements of $A=\{1,1,2,2,\cdots,n,n\}$,

and let $A_i$ be the set of arrangements with the two elements $i,i$ adjacent, for $1\le i\le n$.

Then $\displaystyle\big|\overline{A_1}\cap\cdots\cap\overline{A_n}\big|=|S|-\sum_{i}|A_i|+\sum_{i<j}|A_i\cap A_j|-\sum_{i<j<k}|A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k|+\cdots$

$\displaystyle=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n}-\binom{n}{1}\frac{(2n-1)!}{2^{n-1}}+\binom{n}{2}\frac{(2n-2)!}{2^{n-2}}-\binom{n}{3}\frac{(2n-3)!}{2^{n-3}}+\cdots+(-1)^n\binom{n}{n}\frac{(2n-n)!}{2^{n-n}}$

Comment: Yes. Elegant and self-explanatory. :)